# Washing machine

Tags: plumbing

Stand pipe for washing machine is 7 feet above bottom of washer. Wondering about solutions for problem, can't raise washer or lower stand pipe. Is there a better discharge pump? Or possibly put a loop in the discharge hose to keep water from draining back into machine. Looking for solutions.

Comment: I am going to go with a check valve mounted as low as possible.

Comment: or if you can tee into the stand pipe, a check valve right before the tee. At last then the pump wouldn't have to work so hard... I'm not sure what kind of head Washing machines are usually capable of.